# Is the set of two measurable functions being equal to each other a measurable set?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-measures

Let $(\Omega,F,\mu)$ be a measure space that is not necessarily complete. Let's assume the measure $\mu$ is finite. Let $f$ and $g$ be measurable functions such that $f=g$ almost everywhere. Is it true to state that $\{f=g\}$ is in $F$?

Comment: Yes you are correct. I should have added that if they are inside then immediate consequences are:

Comment: I was trying to ask a very general question from  a question I had about a particular case and I think I ruined it. I modified the question.

Comment: I think your original question was fine, but you wanted $N$ to be a subset of a null set, not the null set.

Comment: I see now that the answer was simpler than I thought. Very silly in my part. Essentially by saying that $\mu\{f \neq g\}=0$ , implicitly we are stating that $\{f \neq g\}$ is in $F$. Thank you

Comment: Please wait. I've deleted that comment since it was wrong. It's not true that $\{f \ne g\}$ is measurable. We only know that $\{f \ne g\} \subseteq N$, where $N$ is a null set.

Comment: I think the current answer for you question is "Yes", but only because you assumed that $f$ and $g$ are measurable. The answer is probably "No" if you don't assume that $f$ and $g$ are measurable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you consider functions $\Omega \to \mathbb R$.
Since you assumed that $f$ and $g$ are measurable, then $f-g$ is measurable. It means that the set $\{f-g = 0\} = \{f-g \ge 0\} \cap \{f-g \le 0\}$ is measurable. So you don't even need "$f=g$ almost everywhere" condition.

On the other hand, if $f$ and $g$ are not measurable, then "$f=g$ almost everywhere" only means that $\{f \ne g\} \subseteq N$, where $\mu(N) = 0$. Since you didn't assume that your space is complete, you can't say that $\{f \ne g\}$ is measurable, and hence can't say that $\{f=g\}$ is measurable. So "$f=g$ almost everywhere" doesn't help here either.